# Prove that for any non-trivial rotation $\rho \in O(V)$ there exists a unique line A

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, rotations

I could use some help with the following $2$ questions.

$1)$ I have to prove that for any non-trivial rotation $\rho \in O(V)$ there exists a unique line A (the axis) such that $\rho(a) = a$  $\forall a \in A$. with $dim(V) = 3$

I tried:

Suppose $A \in O(V)$ and then I have to show $Av = v$. So we are asked to find out whether A has an eigenvalue $\lambda = 1$.

I proved the above, but I am not sure if this is the right way to prove the question.

$2)$ Show that the restriction of $\rho$ to $A^⊥$ is a rotation in $O^+(A^⊥)$, where we write $O^+$ for the orientation preserving elements of $O(V)$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Basically you are right. The characteristic polynomial of $\rho$ has degree 3 (since the space V has dimension 3). Now, every polynomial of degree 3 has a real root and it is by definition eigenvalue of $\rho$. Further since you know that $\rho$ is rotation it does not change vector's length so absolute value of any eigenvalue has to be 1. So you have two cases - eigenvalue is 1 or -1. In the second case it does not preserve orientation.

Comment: Okay, thankyou. I already get the first question I think,. Is there a way you could help me with the second one?

Comment: Not sure what we have to proof. We already know that eigenvalue is 1 so that $\rho$ has corresponding eigenvector as the axis of rotation. I mean, one can decompose $\rho$ as acting in perpendicular space to its eigenvector and since it is rotation on $V$ it is rotation on the subspace.